# Derivative of square root via power series

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, power-series

The power/Taylor series for the complex function $h(w)=\sqrt{w}$ is given by
$$h(w) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!}(w-1)^k$$
where $a_0 = 1, a_{k+1} = (\frac{1}{2}-k)a_k$.
Now is my question: how do I prove that $h$ is differentiable on $D(1;1)$, the disk with center $1$ and radius $1$? Then, how does $h'(w)=\frac{1}{2w}h(w)$?
I found that $h'(w) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_{k+1}}{k!}(w-1)^k$. I'm having difficulties showing that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_{k+1}}{k!}(w-1)^k = \frac{1}{2w} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!}(w-1)^k.$$

Comment: @EricTowers I made some edits. Sorry, I am not the best at asking questions :'( thanks for your input though!

Comment: So a power series is automatically differentiable on its disk of convergence.  Are you able to find the radius of convergence of your series?  Since $a_k$ is a factor of $a_{k+1}$, the ratio test should be very, very easy.  Then, when you formally differentiate your series (by applying the power rule term-wise), can you show $2w h'(w) = h(w)$ by comparing the coefficients in the two series?

Comment: As you have identifed, there is an issue of differentiability at $w = 0$ but they are asking for a Taylor series centered at $1.$ and $h(w)$ is infinitely differentiable there.  And the radius of convergence will be $|x-1|<1$

Comment: @EricTowers The ratio test was simple, I just wanted to verify. However, I'm not able to show $2wh'(w)=h(w)$. Do you have any hints?

Comment: You don't say what you get for your $h'$ in your Question, so it is difficult to diagnose the difficulties you are having showing the differential equation holds.

Comment: @EricTowers I edited the question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I note that $2w = 2(w-1+1) = 2(w-1)+2$.  It can be useful to have all the parts written "centered at $1$".  I also recommend *not* reindexing anything until after computing $(2(w-1)+2)h'(w)$ (since you'll have to reindex one of the two series, after distribution over the addition, to get the powers of $w-1$ to match).